# Backend php program working in xammp but when uploaded values not getting entered in database

Tags: php, xampp

Verification mail in getting sent but values are not going in the database, I have created a user lavvish and it has all the priviledges. Here's my code -

```
$dbc=mysqli_connect('localhost','lavvish','lavvish','lavvish_users');
$q="INSERT INTO temp_users(first,last,email,otp,countrycode,mobile,password)VALUES ('$first','$last','$email','$otp','$cc','$mobile','$EncPwd')";
mysqli_query($dbc,$q);
$_SESSION['email']=$_POST['email'];
header('Location:index.php?login=newuser');
//send verification mail
$to = $email; // Send email to our user
$subject = 'Verification link'; // Give the email a subject 
$message='Your account has been created, activate your account by entering the following otp:'.$otp.'';
$headers = 'From:goLavvish@golavvish.com' . "\r\n"; // Set from headers
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); // Send our email
//Email sent
```

Comment: what error messages are you getting? If you're getting no errors what is showing in the PHP error log?

Comment: 1. If this is your full code, you insert empty fields, please post the full code 2. Please see basic security with mysqli you can prepare your statements, use it. 3. Checkout first com :)

Comment: There are no errors with respect to this page, i.e. User_Signup.php . Just it gets redirected to the required page but the values are not entering the database

Comment: I am entering values in the variables above

Comment: I have tried object oriented mysql an's wel as pdo, still not happening

Comment: I have purchased the server from godaddy .com , it supports multiple domains. Can the problem be there?

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug your query.

For example:

```
if (mysqli_query($link, "your query") === TRUE) {

    printf("Table myCity successfully created.\n");

}
```

Comment: The query is running successfully in xammp server

Comment: This "answer" has the quality of a comment. Please consider to remove befor getting DVs

Comment: Then Please var_dump($_POST) your post arrray . Check it.

Answer (score 0):

Apart for an apparent lack of security, which you ought to think about.[1] I think your issue lies in your SQL statement.

I'd change the line below from:

```
$q="INSERT INTO temp_users(first,last,email,otp,countrycode,mobile,password)VALUES ('$first','$last','$email','$otp','$cc','$mobile','$EncPwd')";
```

so that it now reads:

```
$q="INSERT INTO temp_users (first, last, email, otp, countrycode, mobile, password) VALUES ('$first', '$last', '$email', '$otp', '$cc', '$mobile', '$EncPwd')";
```

As you can see, I've added spaces between the elements. This works for me. If that hasn't helped, try [MySQL Checker](https://www.piliapp.com/mysql-syntax-check/), it's a good resource to check your MySQL syntax.

**EDIT:** If that hasn't worked, I'd check your user priveleges. Make sure that the user has database-specific rights to that database (or table-specific rights if you're going to lock down your db)

**EDIT2:** See kikuyu1's comments in the previous answer:

> @ShubhamKhetan, can you try renaming to this $sql = "INSERT INTO temp_users (first_n, last_n, email_n, otp_n, countrycode_n, mobile_n, password_n) VALUES ($first, $last, $email, $otp, $cc, $mobile, $EncPwd)"; – kikuyu1 11 mins ago
>
> Please check this page to check the researved words in MYSQL dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html. Do not use reserved words in your sql – kikuyu1 6 mins ago

[1]: At least do some sanitization on the inputs, otherwise some unscrupulous hacker will try SQL Injection.

Comment: My select keyword is working but insert is not working. That is, when i am checking if the email already exists in the database foe a manually entered email id, it gives me that it exists, thus user defined is correct, but insertion of values is still not happening. And I am filtering my input, using functions like trim, stripslashes and htmlspecialchars.

Comment: @ShubhamKhetan That's why I suggested editing the INSERT line and not the select line. It's the one that's trying to insert into your fields. Also see kikuyu1's comments about reserved keywords in the other answer, as your fields "first" and "last" are reserved in mysql EDIT: I updated the answer to include the comment

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use PDO. An email will only be sent if the INSERT command is successful, else it will return an error with the error message. To learn about PDO please visit this page http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert_multiple.asp.

Hope it will be helpful.

```html
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "lavvish";
$password = "lavvish";
$dbname = "lavvish_users";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO temp_users (first, last, email, otp, countrycode, mobile, password)
    VALUES ($first, $last, $email, $otp, $cc, $mobile, $EncPwd)";
    // use exec() because no results are returned
    $conn->exec($sql);
    // Save sessions when INSERT is successful
    $_SESSION['email']=$_POST['email'];
    header('Location:index.php?login=newuser');

    $to = $email; // Send email to our user
    $subject = 'Verification link'; 
    // Give the email a subject 
    $message='Your account has been created, activate your account by entering the following otp:'.$otp.'';
    $headers = 'From:goLavvish@golavvish.com' . "\r\n"; 

// Set from headers


  mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 

// Send our email
//Email sent

    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }

$conn = null;
?>
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@gmail.com, 883829, +91, 8237797796, ad9f7083a82fcfd764907dc4c6313ef76abfea21)' at line 2

Comment: @ShubhamKhetan, can you try renaming to this `$sql = "INSERT INTO temp_users (first_n, last_n, email_n, otp_n, countrycode_n, mobile_n, password_n)
    VALUES ($first, $last, $email, $otp, $cc, $mobile, $EncPwd)";`

Comment: Please check this page to check the researved words in MYSQL http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html. Do not use reserved words in your sql